# Why is this short snippet of php not pulling the mp4 file from my Wordpress Media Library?

Tags: php, wordpress, html, video

I'm attempting to add a video background to a homepage template for a website that I'm developing. I've used ACF Pro fields to add an option to upload both mp4 and webm files that returns the URL of the video.

I then am attempting to modify the php of the home template to display the video using HTML5 and by calling the custom field I created where the user uploads the file.

For some reason the video isn't displaying, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
<div class="intro-block">

<!-- My Edits-->    

    <?php
        $video_background_mp4=get_field( 'video_background_mp4');
        $video_background_webm=get_field( 'video_background_webm');
    ?>

    <video>
        <source src="<?php echo $video_background_mp4; ?>" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="<?php echo $video_background_webm; ?>" type="video/webm">
    </video>
  <!-- End of my edits-->
    <div class="text-holder">
        <div class="container">
            <?php if( $title = get_field( 'title' )) : ?>
                <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if( $find_btn_link = get_field( 'find_btn_link' )) : ?>
                 <a href="<?php echo $find_btn_link; ?>" class="btn btn-blue white-border"><?php echo get_field( 'find_btn_text' ); ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What is returned from your two `get_field()` calls?